# How to handle UI-blocking code on App launch

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have an app that reads from an sqlite db in order to build the UI.

However, reading from sqlite is blocking and could possibly cause an ANR. What is the best practice to run UI-blocking code that is needed before the UI can be drawn?

Comment: In that case you can use splash screen and display some animation on the splash screen. and at the same time you can use Asynctask to access your db and read the information.

Comment: @Setu I did think of implementing a splash scrren. However, sqlite might take less than a second to load. Is it good practice to display a splash for such a short time?

Comment: But as you say it will block your UI, and when you say blocking UI in android it is considered BAD practice be it for 1 second or 10. So best thing is too use splash screen or you can create an empty fragment or activity and display progress dialog in Async task, choice is yours. But never block UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `AsyncTask` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

When you've completed your processing, use `onPostExecute (Result result)` to update your UI.

EDIT:

Just to elaborate, when you implement `doInBackground (Params... params)` in your `AsyncTask`, don't interact with your UI thread as that method is not executed on the `UI thread`.

If you need to update your UI, implement `onPreExecute()`, for updates **before** doing your background tasks, `onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)`, for updates **while** doing background tasks, and/or `onPostExecute (Result result)`, for when your `AsyncTask` **completes** doing its work. The "usage" section of the developer docs (from the link above) has a nice little example for `onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)`

EDIT 2:

Handling UI

It's good practice to show an (`Indeterminate`) progress bar while the `AsyncTask` is running.

An example layout XML is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- Use whichever style of progress bar you need, this one is a rotating circle and is indeterminate. Note, it is "gone" by default. The visibility toggle is handled by the AsyncTask -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/uiContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- your UI here -->
    </LinearLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()` method:

```
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressBar.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    uiContainer.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE); // optional, up to you if you need to hide your UI
    // Do other things here
}
```

And in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute (Result result)`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Result result)
{
    progressBar.setVisibility (View.GONE);
    uiContainer.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); // refer to the optional above in onPreExecute
    // Do other things here
}
```

Again, this is an example, customize/use it as you see fit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do know about AsyncTask and its implementation (as tagged in the question). What i was asking is how I should handle the UI while the AsyncTask is taking place.

Comment: Typically an indefinite ProgressBar is shown in the middle of the screen until content is loaded. You can hide it in onPostExecute.

Comment: @mushroom, oh sorry, didn't notice the tags, I'm a stack overflow newbie XD. Might be good to highlight that in the question also. 

But as @Nathan Walters said, an `Indeterminate` (official name in the docs) progress bar to show that something is happening is good practice. I usually wrap the UI and the progress bar in a relative layout, center the progress bar and toggle the visibility of the UI and the progress bar between `View.GONE` (or `View.INVISIBLE` for your UI container) and `View.VISIBLE`. I'll edit my answer above to demonstrate

Comment: @mushroom finished the update, that should cover it :). If there's anything I've missed, gimme a heads up